# Swift 3: Type error of generic delegate type with concrete consumer type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a problem with a generic delegate `ProducerDelegate`, which will have an argument (`Int`) with the same type as the consumer `IntConsumer` method needs it (`Int`)

If the delegate methods will be called and I want to use the received value `element`

```
func didProduce<Int>(from: Producer<Int>, element: Int) {
    output(element: element)
}
```

to call an other method I got the error:

**`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Int'`**

And my question is why?

I explain my case (and here is a playground file with the same source: http://tuvalu.s3.amazonaws.com/so/generic-delegate.playground.zip )

I have a generic producer class `Producer` with a protocol for produced elements `ProducerDelegate`:

```
import Foundation

/// Delegate for produced elements
protocol ProducerDelegate : class {

    /// Called if a new element is produced
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - from: producer
    ///     - element: produced element
    func didProduce<T>(from: Producer<T>, element: T)
}

/// Produces new element
class Producer<T> {

    /// The object that acts as consumer of produced element
    weak var delegate: ProducerDelegate?

    /// The producing element
    let element: T

    /// Initializes and returns a `Producer` producing the given element
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - element: An element which will be produced
    init(element: T) {
        self.element = element
    }

    /// Produces the object given element
    func produce() {
        delegate?.didProduce(from: self, element: element)
    }
}
```

In a consumer, the producer is injected:

```
/// Consumes produced `Int` elements and work with it
class IntConsumer {

    /// Producer of the `Int`s
    let producer: Producer<Int>

    /// Initializes and returns a `IntConsumer` having the given producer
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - producer: `Int` producer
    init(producer: Producer<Int>) {
        self.producer = producer
        self.producer.delegate = self
    }

    /// outputs the produced element
    fileprivate func output(element: Int) {
        print(element)
    }
}
```

Now, I wanted add the extension for the delegate like this:

```
extension IntConsumer: ProducerDelegate {
    func didProduce<Int>(from: Producer<Int>, element: Int) {
        output(element: element)
    }
}
```

But, it fails with:
**`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Int'`**

The Swift compiler says I should cast the element to `Int`, like:

```
func didProduce<Int>(from: Producer<Int>, element: Int) {
    output(element: element as! Int)
}
```

but it fails, too

But, if the generic type has an other concrete type, like `String`, I can cast and it works:

```
func didProduce<String>(from: Producer<String>, element: String) {
    guard let element2 = element as? Int else { return }

    output(element: element2)
}
```

So, my current solution is to work with a typealias, that I don't have to put wrong types in the delegate method:

```
extension IntConsumer: ProducerDelegate {
    typealias T = Int

    func didProduce<T>(from: Producer<T>, element: T) {
        guard let element = element as? Int else { return }

        output(element: element)
    }
}
```

I hope someone can explain me my error and give me a better solution.

Comment: Your playground compiled without errors.

Comment: @ArtemNovichkov Because the playground uses my last working solution as default. Please uncomment the error cases, than you can see the error

Comment: Note that the `typealias` in your last working solution is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

Your protocol requirement

```
func didProduce<T>(from: Producer<T>, element: T)
```

says "I can be called with *any* type of element and a producer of the same type of element". But that's not what you want to express – an `IntConsumer` can *only* consume `Int` elements.

You then implement this requirement as:

```
func didProduce<Int>(from: Producer<Int>, element: Int) {...}
```

which defines a *new* generic placeholder called "`Int`" – which will shadow the standard library's `Int` inside the method. Because *your* "`Int`" could represent any type, the compiler rightly tells you that you cannot pass it to a parameter that expects an *actual* `Int`.

You don't want generics here – you want an [associated type](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID189) instead:

```
/// Delegate for produced elements
protocol ProducerDelegate : class {

    associatedtype Element

    /// Called if a new element is produced
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - from: producer
    ///     - element: produced element
    func didProduce(from: Producer<Element>, element: Element)
}
```

This protocol requirement now says "I can be called with only a specific type of element, which the conforming type will decide".

You can then simply implement the requirement as:

```
extension IntConsumer : ProducerDelegate {

    // Satisfy the ProducerDelegate requirement – Swift will infer that
    // the associated type "Element" is of type Int.
    func didProduce(from: Producer<Int>, element: Int) {
        output(element: element)
    }
}
```

(Note the removal of the `<Int>` generic placeholder).

However, because we're now using an associated type, you cannot use `ProducerDelegate` as an actual type – only a generic placeholder. This is because the compiler now has no idea what the associated type is if you talk only in terms of `ProducerDelegate`, so you cannot possibly use protocol requirements that depend on that associated type.

One possible solution to this problem is to define a [type erasure](http://robnapier.net/erasure) in order to wrap the delegate method, and allowing us to express the associated type in terms of a generic placeholder:

```
// A wrapper for a ProducerDelegate that expects an element of a given type.
// Could be implemented as a struct if you remove the 'class' requirement from 
// the ProducerDelegate.
// NOTE: The wrapper will hold a weak reference to the base.
class AnyProducerDelegate<Element> : ProducerDelegate {

    private let _didProduce : (Producer<Element>, Element) -> Void

    init<Delegate : ProducerDelegate>(_ base: Delegate) where Delegate.Element == Element {
        _didProduce = { [weak base] in base?.didProduce(from: $0, element: $1) }
    }

    func didProduce(from: Producer<Element>, element: Element) {
        _didProduce(from, element)
    }
}
```

In order to prevent retain cycles, `base` is captured weakly by the type-erasure.

You'll then want to change your `Producer`'s `delegate` property to use this type-erased wrapper:

```
var delegate: AnyProducerDelegate<Element>?
```

and then use the wrapper when assigning the delegate in `IntConsumer`:

```
/// Consumes produced `Int` elements and work with it
class IntConsumer {

    // ...        

    init(producer: Producer<Int>) {
        self.producer = producer
        self.producer.delegate = AnyProducerDelegate(self)
    }

    // ...

}
```

Although, one downside to this approach is that the `delegate` won't be set to `nil` if the consumer is deallocated, instead calling `didProduce` on it will just silently fail. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a better way of achieving this – would certainly be interested if anyone else has a better idea.